# Find the sum of an infinite sequence(not a series)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $n$ be a natural number and let $\langle n\rangle$ denote the closest integer to $\sqrt n$. Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^  \infty \frac{2^{\langle n\rangle}+2^{-\langle n\rangle}}{2^n}$$ I started putting the values of $n$ to see a pattern. It looks like a Geometric Progression but I am unable to sum it. Also, if a better approach exists, please share. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if this problem has an analytic solution?

Comment: The answer is $3$. If one group the terms with same $\langle n\rangle$, it is not that hard to turn this into a telescoping series.

Comment: A *series* is the sum of a sequence (usually countably infinite since a finite sum is just called "a sum", and uncountably infinite sets cannot have a defined sum unless all but countably many terms are zero).

Comment: Sorry, I was incorrect, this question *is* a duplicate, the question, process, and therefore answer are exactly the same.